# Make video from .png files in Hitfilm Express

Tags: video, blender

I'm trying to make a video in Hitfilm Express.

I've imported a folder full of .png files which were rendered in Blender.

I then dragged them into the editor > Video 1 section.

Instead of playing 29.97fps, Hitfilm is playing one single .png image per ~5 seconds.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You can import the folder as an image sequence. To do so, click on the small arrow next to *import* and choose *import as image sequence*. Then choose the folder that contains your frames and click ok. You might have to adjust the framerate to match your project in the media settings.

Answer (score 1):

By default, images put into hitfilm won't be single frames, a good way to counteract this is by setting your scrubber on the timeline to a frame after the first image, cutting it and dragging the next image to it.

In my experience, this is tedious and there are editors built more specifically for this task, such as ffmpeg.

There is also the option to export directly to the mp4 format. (here are some instructions): https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34586/save-as-a-video-as-mp4